# Trouble with local object and their value

Tags: vb.net

I am programming with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 in VB.net for Windows CE 6.0 - framework 3.5

I have an issue with the following code:

```
REFRESH SUB (byval myVar as pl30message)

    AggiornaTim.Enabled = False
    Debug.WriteLine("myVar")

    If Not myVar.isOnlineIgnoreWeight Then CaricaPesoInButton(OnlineBtnPeso,myVar)

    AggiornaTim.Enabled = true

END SUB

CaricaPesoInButton(byref tmpButton as button, byval myVar as pl30messagge)

    debug.writeline("myVar")

END SUB
```

---

AggiornaTim is my timer, 300 ms

myVar is the problem

The only "caller" of REFRESH sub is timer event, i disable it right after enter in the sub

How is possible that myVar is different in the two debug.write ?

Comment: Please post the exact VB.NET code that you have. `REFRESH SUB` is not valid syntax, and I suspect you have: `Debug.WriteLine(myVar)` (without quotes around myVar) am I right?

Comment: You are right! I tried to compact and clean code with non relevant parts...is myVar without quote and the name is "AggiornaTim_Tick" instead of refresh

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, the only thing that could cause a change to myVar is the call to `isOnlineIgnoreWeight` method (I suppose it's a property?), so I would first check if that property changes anything inside the myVar object. If it's not that, then it's something else in your code that you haven't posted here.

I would also make sure that the two debug outputs that you see really are from your two methods, and not two outputs from the same AggiornaTim_Tick method. Some step-by-step debugging would be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks, i'll still trying some step by step debug.
Yes, it's a readonly property that just check a value, therefore it shouldn't change anything :(